# how to set cert when calling createChannel in Fabric Node SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

Help me please with channel creation. 
In node sdk i have

```
// // extract the channel config bytes from the envelope to be signed
const envelope = fs.readFileSync(`${channelConfigPath+channelName}.tx`),
 channelConfig = client.extractChannelConfig(envelope),
 signature     = client.signChannelConfig(channelConfig);

 // get an admin based transactionID
 // send to orderer
 const request = {
   config: channelConfig,
   signatures: [signature],
   name: channelName,
   txId: client.newTransactionID(true)
 };

client.createChannel(request)
```

But i get error in `docker logs orderer.example.com`

```
-2018-06-26 14:41:04.631 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 120 Signature set  did not satisfy policy /Channel/Application/Gov1MSP/Admins
-2018-06-26 14:41:04.631 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 121 == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/Gov1MSP/
-2018-06-26 14:41:04.631 UTC [policies] func1 -> DEBU 122 Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ Gov1MSP.Admins ]
-2018-06-26 14:41:04.631 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 123 Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Application/ChannelCreationPolicy
-2018-06-26 14:41:04.631 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 124 == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Application/ChannelCreationPolicy
-2018-06-26 14:41:04.631 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 125 [channel: usachannel] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 172.18.0.1:46638 because of error: Error authorizing update: Error validating DeltaSet: Policy for [Groups] /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining
-2018-06-26 14:41:04.631 UTC [orderer/common/server] func1 -> DEBU 126 Closing Broadcast stream
```

So, how should I set cert from `/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp` in Fabric Node SDK?

P.S. with the cert above i can create channel using `peer channel create`

Comment: I am using 

    "fabric-ca-client": "^1.1.2",
    "fabric-client": "^1.1.2"

Answer (score 3):

I am using "^1.2.0" version for fabric-client and fabric-ca-client.

To set the signing identity of the client you need to use the [setAdminSigningIdentity](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/Client.html#setAdminSigningIdentity__anchor) method.

For the private key I used the private key in the keystore directory of the msp folder.
In my case it was: "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore".
And for the certificate I used the same folder but the file "signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem".

Then you need to use newTransaction(true) because if you don't it will use the userContext which you do not want because you provided the adminSigningIdentity.